# Recursive integer solution of the equation: $a^2-2b^2=\pm 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction, algebraic-number-theory

> Consider $a_0=a_1=1$ and $a_k=2a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}$ for $k\ge2$.
>   Similarly $b_0=0,b_1=1$ and $b_k=2b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}$ for $k\ge 2$.

I want to prove that for every natural $k$ the pair $(a_k,b_k)$ is an integer solution of the equation $a^2-2b^2=\pm 1$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Z$. Of course you can find other recursions for other indices (even/odd). This would be ok for me.

Now the idea is to prove it by induction. I tried, but I had some difficulties since by even $k$ we have the solution for $+1$ and for odd $k$ the one for $-1$ and I should prove also this by induction. However I cannot see how since the $a_k,b_k$ are too dependent on the others. Making computations you can see what I mean.

> Another idea was to consider two distinct recursions: one for even values of $k$ and another one for odd $k$ and proving by induction the two recursions separately. However I cannot see these recursions. Anyone does?

Does anyone know how to do the induction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the fact that

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n\right)
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
b_n=-\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n-\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2 \sqrt{2}}.$$

These expressions can be proved by induction (there are also well-known methods to derive the general term of a linear recursive relation. You can read about it for example in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).)

Therefore, we have

$$a_n^2=\frac{1}{4}\left\{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{2 n}+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{2 n}+2\left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)^n\right\}
$$

and

$$2b_n^2=\frac14\left\{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{2 n}+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{2 n}-2\left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)^n\right\}
$$

so

$$a_n^2-2b_n^2=\frac14\left\{4\left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)^n\right\}
=(-1)^n.$$

**EDIT** (a method to derive $a_n$): let us define

$$F(x):=\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Then clearly $F^{(n)}(0)=a_n$. Now,

$$F''(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n+2}\frac{x^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}+2\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}+2\sum_{n\geq1}a_{n}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
=F(x)+2F'(x).$$

So $F$ is a function that satisfies the linear second order ODE

$$F''(x)-2F'(x)-F(x)=0$$

and the initial conditions $F(0)=1,F'(0)=1$. Solving the differential equation we obtain

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) x}+e^{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) x}\right),$$

so the general form of $a_n$ is achieved after $n$-fold differentiation.

Comment: Which particular method are you referring to? Regarding to derive the general term. Could you show it in this answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can prove the following claim by induction. Note that this claim is one claim containing 4 equations. We will prove these equations simultaneously.

**Claim**
\begin{align}
a_{2m}^2 - 2b_{2m}^2 &= 1\\
a_{2m+1}^2 - 2b_{2m+1}^2 &= -1\\
a_{2m}a_{2m+1} - 2b_{2m}b_{2m+1} &= -1\\
a_{2m-1}a_{2m} - 2b_{2m-1}b_{2m} &= 1\\
\end{align}

**Sketch of the proof the claim**

- First step: You can easily show this for $m=1$.
- Then try to prove this claim for $m+1$ i.e.

\begin{align*}
a_{2m+2}^2 - 2b_{2m+2}^2 &= 1\\
a_{2m+3}^2 - 2b_{2m+3}^2 &= -1\\
a_{2m+2}a_{2m+3} - 2b_{2m+2}b_{2m+3} &= -1\\
a_{2m+1}a_{2m+2} - 2b_{2m+1}b_{2m+2} &= 1\\
\end{align*}

This should be straight forward.

**Comment on the straightforwardness**

Let me prove the first line:

\begin{align*}
a_{2m+2}^2 - 2b_{2m+2}^2 &= (2a_{2m+1} - a_{2m})^2 - (2b_{2m+1} - b_{2m})^2\\
&= 4a_{2m+1}^2 + a_{2m}^2 -4a_{2m+1}a_{2m} - 8b_{2m+1}^2 - 2b_{2m}^2 + 4b_{2m+1}a_{2m}\\
&= 4(a_{2m+1}^2 -2b_{2m+1}^2) + (a_{2m}^2 -2 b_{2m}^2) - 4(a_{2m}a_{2m+1} - b_{2m}a_{2m+1})\\
&= - 4 + 1 -4\\
&=1
\end{align*}

**Note**

Sometimes it is hard to do induction over one claim. In cases like this, proving a stronger claim makes the proof easier.

**Edit**

There were couple of typos about the negative signs. I have fixed them.

Comment: What you say that "should be straightforward" seems to be far away from that.

Comment: I tried to prove the first two claims of your answer but I obtained nothing. I really would appreciate more details in these answer. My problem wasn't the idea of the induction, but the computations.

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry for any confusion, I didn't mean easy, it is just computations. Richard since you are interested in the computations, I have included the proof the first line for $m+1$ case.

Comment: @iamvegan Thanks, yet the proof you included (line 1) relies on claim 3 ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes you are right. But I am proving that claim by induction. Proof uses the claim for the case $m$.

Comment: @iamvegan So then you prove the claim by double induction on two different, though related, concepts. Nice...and indeed not straightforward. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you :) Sorry, I thought it was, my bad.

Comment: @DonAntonio pretty standard from viewpoint of quadratic forms and their automorphism groups. I made an answer.

Comment: Richard, that's why I take care of all the lines simultaneously. I am assuming line 1,2,3,4 for the case $m$. Then I prove them for the case $m+1$. It might not be possible to prove the lines independently.

Comment: Ok, I am glad. That's why I have put them inside one "Claim". The claim is all 4 equations.

Answer (score 0):

I should emphasize that this is just the continued fraction for $\sqrt 2.$

Usually it is not so pretty to combine the $1$ and $-1$ cases in Pell $x^2 - n y^2.$ However: If $$ x^2 - 2 y^2 = \delta  $$ with all integers, then
$$ (x+2y)^2 - 2 (x+y)^2 = - \delta.  $$
That is, take the column vector of integers

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The matrix of transformation is
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The fact you are trying to prove is just Cayley-Hamilton for this matrix. The trace is $2$ while the determinant is $-1.$ The characteristic equation is then $\lambda^2 - 2 \lambda - 1,$ or  $\lambda^2 = 2 \lambda + 1.$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_n \\
y_n
\end{array}
\right),
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+2} \\
y_{n+2}
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right),
$$
while $A^2 = 2A + I.$